# Growing List Items as Graph

Tags: javascript, css, animation, graph

I have a list which list items grow dynamically with JavaScript until 100%. This works.
But I want it to look something like [this](http://starflower.at/stackoverflow/growing-divs.jpg)

So my problem here is. How can I make them grow to the top. I tried with height, but then they grew to the bottom. Also rotating them with CSS doesn’t really work, because the more list items are added the more the list moves to the bottom…

Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you!!

Comment: You will need to use absolute positioning on your elements, referencing the 'bottom:' property, and then adjusting their height will cause them to "grow up"

Comment: @jib, in addition, it is recommended to use `relative` positioning for the widget's top container, as to have more control in positioning the widget itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning for the `li`-elements. Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/J5pB7/

```
ul{
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #666;
    position:relative;
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:green;
}
#a{
    height:50%;
    margin-left:30px;
}
#b{
    margin-left:80px;
    height:10%;
}
#c{
    margin-left:130px;
    height:90%
}
```

Comment: no problem! if you want, you can accept the solution. take a look at the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: you can't click the tick under the upvote-thing? however, no problem, glad to help you! :)